# Split one sentence with ｢ and square brackets into multiple

Tags: perl

I have sentences of this pattern in the dictionary text data:

`I have ｢an absolute [a deadly] abhorrence of ｢laziness [greasy food].`

Is there a way that I can split it into 4 sentences as follows to make it more searchable in the dictionary (using Perl)?

`I have an absolute abhorrence of laziness.`

`I have an absolute abhorrence of greasy food.`

`I have a deadly abhorrence of laziness.`

`I have a deadly abhorrence of greasy food.`

Comment: There could be any number (> 0) of words of any part of speech between `｢` and `[`. So is between `[` and `]`. Also there could be any number of pairs of `｢…[…]` in a sentence. @zdim

Comment: OK, thank you -- just answered the other question as I was typing it :)  (can be any number of pairs)

Comment: Do you have a specific question? You have an end goal, but applying some reduction would lead to some questions like "how to split a string into tokens in perl" and "how to loop over a list in perl" which have many answers on the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, parse into

```perl
my @def = (
   [ "I have " ],
   [ "an absolute", "a deadly" ],
   [ " abhorrence of " ],
   [ "laziness", "greasy food" ],
   [ "." ],
);
```

This can be achieved using the following, a validating parser:

```perl
my @def;
for ( $str ) {
   / \G ( [^｢]+ ) /xgc
      and push @def, [ $1 ];

   if ( / \G ｢ /xgc ) {
      / \G ( [^｢\[\]]+ ) [ ] \[ ( [^｢\[\]]+ ) \] /xgc
         or die( "Bad sequence at offset ".( pos() - 1 )."\n" );

      push @def, [ $1, $2 ];
      redo;
   }

   /\G \z /xgc
      and last;

   die( "Should not happen" );
}
```

Then find the product. This can be achieved using the following:

```perl
use Algorithm::Loops qw( NestedLoops );

my $iter = NestedLoops( \@def );
while ( my @parts = $iter->() ) {
   say join "", @parts;
}
```

or

```perl
use Algorithm::Loops qw( NestedLoops );

NestedLoops( \@def, sub { say join "", @_; } );
```

Answer (score 4):

An interesting problem.  Here is one solution.

For now replace the open paren `｢` by `<` and adjust the sentence.<sup>†</sup> Take an example string:

```
word <a A1[b b1] and more <a A2[b b2] but <a A3[b b3] end
```

1. Split the string into tokens: substrings containing alternatives `<...[...]`, and substrings with groups of words around them.  Once we are here, break each alternatives-substring into the two alternatives and put that in an arrayref.  So we'll have an array with:

   ```
   ('word', ['a A1', 'b b1'], 'and more', ['a A2', 'b b2'], 

       'but', ['a A3', 'b b3'], 'end')
   ```
2. Identify indices of alternatives (`1,3,5` here)
3. Create all combinations of these indices (as a set, so find the set of all subsets, the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set)).  For the indices in a subset we take the first alternative when composing a sentence, for those not in the subset we take the second (or the other way round)
4. Go through the tokens array and print, selecting the alternatives as described above

I use [Algorithm::Combinatorics](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::Combinatorics) for combinations but there are of course other libraries.

A program with a test sentence introduced above (and only ascii characters)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use List::Util qw(any none);    
use Algorithm::Combinatorics qw(subsets);

my $str = q(word <a A1[b b1] and more <a A2[b b2] but <a A3[b b3] end);
say $str;

 my @tokens = 
     map { /^</ ? [ /<([^\[]+) \[([^\]]+)\]/x ] : $_ }
     split /(<[^\[]+ \[[^\]]+\])/x, $str;
 #say "@tokens";

 my @idx = grep { ref $tokens[$_] eq 'ARRAY' } 0..$#tokens;
 #say "@idx";

my @subsets = subsets( \@idx );

for my $ss (@subsets) {
    my @take_0 = @$ss;
    for my $iw (0..$#tok) {
        if    (none { $iw == $_ } @idx)    { print " $tok[$iw] " }
        elsif (any  { $iw == $_ } @take_0) { print " $tok[$iw]->[0] " }
        else                               { print " $tok[$iw]->[1] " }
    }
    say '';
}
```

There are great simplifications considering all kinds of sentence structure an details from natural languages. There is plenty of room for code improvement, and there's a bit of cleanup to do (extra spaces, for one), but it does print all combinations with alternative phrases.

The library can generate one item at a time: when invoked in scalar context its functions return an iterator, on which `->next` gives the next item. This is important for very large sets of items.

---

Here is a program with the sentence given in the question.  (The solution above has ascii (`<`) instead of the `｢` character, as some systems still have problems with Unicode.  Other than that the program is the same.)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use List::Util qw(any none);    
use Algorithm::Combinatorics qw(subsets);

use utf8;
use open qw(:std :encoding(UTF-8));

my $str = q(I have ｢an absolute [a deadly] abhorrence of ｢laziness [greasy food].);
say $str;

my @tokens = 
    map { /^｢/ ? [ /｢([^\[]+) \[([^\]]+)\]/x ] : $_ }
    split /(｢[^\[]+ \[[^\]]+\])/x, $str;

my @idx = grep { ref $tokens[$_] eq 'ARRAY' } 0..$#tokens;

my @subsets = subsets( \@idx );

for my $ss (@subsets) {
    my @take_0 = @$ss;
    for my $iw (0..$#tokens) {
        if    (none { $iw == $_ } @idx)    { print " $tokens[$iw] " }
        elsif (any  { $iw == $_ } @take_0) { print " $tokens[$iw]->[0] " }
        else                               { print " $tokens[$iw]->[1] " }
    }
    say '';
}
```